# Error: "detox-cli" package is not meant to be installed locally, exiting

Tags: react-native, detox

I am trying to follow [this link](https://blog.logrocket.com/end-to-end-testing-in-react-native-with-detox/) to use detox for e2e testing for my react native app. I did it successfully once, but I removed e2e folder, was conducting some experiments, now I am not able to run `detox init -r jest`
every time I run this line it gives me this error:

```
Error: "detox-cli" package is not meant to be installed locally, exiting...
HINT: Remove the local installation and reinstall it globally:
  npm uninstall detox-cli
  npm install -g detox-cli
```

I have tried the solution in the hint, but it didn't resolve the issue, any suggestions?
If I uninstall and run the command, same error shows up.
when I install it, this is what I see (node version and detox-cli version)

```
/Users/.../.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/detox -> /Users/.../.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/detox-cli/cli.js
+ detox-cli@18.13.0
updated 1 package in 1.358s
```

-----Update:
I just tried this and worked:

```
/Users/.../.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/detox init -r jest
```

Comment: Could you exclude the possibility that you have Detox installed globally, i.e. `npm uninstall -g detox`?